# How to understand this Python code for Twosum

Tags: python

The leetcode twosum problem:
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

I read someone's python code as following:

```
vis = {}            
for i,num in enumerate(nums):
            diff = target - num
            if diff in vis:
                return[vis[diff],i]
            vis[num] = i
```

I can understand the majority of logic behind this code. However why the last line have to be in this order?  It seems weird to me to make assignment after the return statement. 
So I tried to move it to other places, but this will output null. Why does the last line have to be at that place?

Comment: This code **returns** a value when it **finds** an answer, so there is nothing to do anymore and the algo could stop. Otherwise, it adds a new value to a dictionary and proceeds to a next number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement is within the `if` statement, so it will only execute if `diff` is in `vis`, i.e., when you have found a `diff` you wanted, such that `nums[diff] + nums[i] == target` is `True`. If that doesn't happen, only then the final statement will be executed. So, it would add the `diff` for a later comparison and would move on with the next iteration.